# Electricity off while shrinking database, how can I recover my database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, recovery

While i execute shrink database, the electricity has been gone down, I can't access my database now, it is (In Recovery), how can i recover it?? Note: it is a very huge database: 25 GB.

**EDIT:**

My question on serverfault.com: https://serverfault.com/questions/395067/electricity-gone-off-while-shrinking-database-how-can-i-recover-my-database

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wait patiently for it to recover.  This is what is supposed to happen.  While waiting, try to track down your latest backup, just in case.  I suggest a small investment in a UPS will avoid this problem in the future.

Comment: can it continue recovery after a restart????

Comment: @MSS If you restart the system while a database is in recovery, the recovery process will restart from the beginning again. Preferably, leave it be until recovery completes.

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanx, it is ok again!